# how to get the values of textbox to a variable in script?

Tags: javascript

I have written a script like this

```
function calculateDiff(){

    _start = "1:00 PM";
    _end = "1:00 AM";

    _start_time = parseAMDate(_start);
    _end_time = parseAMDate(_end);

    if (_end_time < _start_time){
        _end_time = parseAMDate(_end,1);
    }

    var difference= _end_time - _start_time;

    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 36e5),
        minutes = Math.floor(difference % 36e5 / 60000);
    if (parseInt(hours) >= 0 ){
        if (minutes == 0){
            minutes = "00";
        }
        alert(hours+":"+minutes);
    }
}
function parseAMDate(input, next_day) {

    var dateReg = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\s*(AM|PM)/;

    var hour, minute, result = dateReg.exec(input);

    if (result) {
        hour = +result[1];
        minute = +result[2];

        if (result[3] === 'PM' && hour !== 12) {
            hour += 12;
        }
    }
    if (!next_day) {
        return new Date(1970, 01, 01, hour, minute).getTime();
    }else{
        return new Date(197var start = document.getElementById("usr1").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("usr2").value;0, 01, 02, hour, minute).getTime();
      }
   }
```

here ,for  _start and _end ,i have given values now i want these values should get from a textbox for that i have written code like

```
<form action="calculateDiff()">
Select  start time:<input type="time" name="usr1">
 Select  end time: <input type="time" name="usr2">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when i select time in text box(usr1),how to get the time to the script function?
plz help me

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add an `id` property to the input fields:

```
<form action="calculateDiff()">
    Select  start time:<input type="time" name="usr1" id="startTime">
    Select  end time: <input type="time" name="usr2" id="endTime">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now we can use `document.getElementById` to get direct access to the html element:

```
var start = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
var end = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
```

`document.getElementById("usr1")` will return the HTML textfield object itself and it has a few properties. One of them is `value` which represents the content inside the textfield (you can even change it using javascript).

Read more about the input element here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: Keep in mind that this would require an id to be added to the input tags in addition to what is currently there.

Comment: my total code is this how do i calculate time difference

Comment: in my url shows like  calculateDiff()?usr1=01%3A00&usr2=02%3A00 ,web page not found error is comming

Comment: @NagaPhaneendra the `action` property on the form is the address to send the data to. You may want to use `onsubmit` instead. Anyways, please read more about html forms [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_start = document.getElementsByName('usr1')[0].value; //It will fetch the value of the first element in the DOM with the name usr1
_end = document.getElementsByName('usr2')[0].value; //It will fetch the value of the first element in the DOM with the name usr2
```

Comment: in my url it was showing like calculateDiff()?usr1=01%3A00&usr2=02%3A00

Comment: Please update you HTML code if you are really using `id` for text box and then check your `else` part of `if (!next_day)` for syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

you can get value of input like this

```
var _start = document.getElementsByName("usr1")[0].value;
var _end = document.getElementsByName("usr2")[0].value;
```

Comment: in my url it was getting like this calculateDiff()?usr1=01%3A00&usr2=02%3A00

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas What is the difference in your answer while comparing with my answer?

Comment: @JohnR dude you are also correct i did't see your answer in feeds

Comment: @NagaPhaneendra why you are passing function in action you can simply get your restult change the input type submit to button